# Adding silverlight control at runtime

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, html

I want to add a silverlight control to a div panel at runtime (dynamically) ( on an aspx or user control) . How can one achieve this?

Comment: never tried it, but have you tried just adding the usual silverlight <object> tag (etc)?

Comment: Yes.. I have used object tag and it works.. but I want to add it at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to create plugin dynamically

> function createSL(pathToXAP, parentElement)
>   {

```
Silverlight.createObjectEx(
{
    source: pathToXAP,
    parentElement: document.getElementById(parentElement),
    id: "sltest",
    properties: { width: "100%", height: "100%", background: "white", version: "4.0.50401.0" },
    events: { onError: onSilverlightError }
});
```

}

pathToXAP -e.g. '<%= ResolveUrl("~/ClientBin/MySilverlight.xap") %>'
parentElement is div's name

This function you can call from JS or from Silverlight as you need

Comment: can we add this function in code behind? Any dlls required for the same?

Comment: this is JS function (see createSL). Silverlight.createObjectEx is defined in Silverlight.js file. If you create silverlight project with  Web application in Visual Studio this file will be added

Comment: somehow, the control is not being displayed